# Fish Shell Fatal Error : Not A Git Repository

Tags: 16.04, command-line, git, fish, dash-shell

I have been using [Fish Shell](https://fishshell.com/) for a while now, however, a day or two ago, this error started appearing on execution of every command within the shell:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Here is a screenshot:

[image: fish shell error]

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to resolve it. I was thinking of reinstalling but wondered why this is happening in the first place.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you display any git info in your fish prompt?

Comment: yes, as a developer, I do use git everyday.

Comment: Can you show your fish shell configuration file (dunno, maybe `.fishrc` or something like that, where the prompt is set)?